# Как узнать координаты углов зоны видимости карты Google maps api

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

Проблема в том есть овер 999999 маркеров на карте, нужно вытягивать с базы только те что входят в зону видимости, соответственно широта и долгота находиться в диапазоне левого/правого верхнего/нижнего угла. Но как достать координаты углов зоны видимости?
Гугл апи смотрел, ничего подходящего нету.
Работаю с js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, метод `.getBounds()` это то, что Вам нужно.

Внизу код, который может Вам пригодиться.
При изменении границ карты (zoom или просто карту подвинули) код проверяет все маркеры (массив `markers`) и загоняет в объект `visibles` те, что внутри видимого окна.

```
map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
        visibles = {};
        for (var i=0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            if (map.getBounds().contains(markers[i].getPosition())) {
                visibles[i] = markers[i];
            }
        }
}
```

*Замечание:* пожалуйста учтите, что приведенный код может работать не корректно если у Вас включен clustering маркеров

Comment: Спасибо, а на какой позиции каждая координата?

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду позицию каждого маркера в списке? Если да, то я не уверен, что api даст такую информацию. Скорее всего надо высчитывать самому. Позиция маркера считается от его удалённости от текущего центра карты.